# Discord.JS For Every Request Reply With a New Code

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make something work.
When they do [!btc] it sends an embed where it shows a address code from blockchain.com

Is it possible for every new request to send a new address **code**?

My current code:

```
case "btc":
          const btc = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#003087')
            .setTitle('Payment Method: Bitcoin! <:btc:878247766067908610>')
            .setDescription("Bitcoin Adress: **code**")
            .setFooter("Created and Developed by ❤️")
          //message.channel.send()
          setTimeout(() => {
            message.channel.send(btc);
          }, 5500);
          message.delete();
          message.channel.send(`<a:loading:885542082234629809> Please wait..`)
            .then((msg) => {
              setTimeout(function () {
                msg.edit(`${message.author.toString()}.`);
              }, 5000)
            });
          break;
```

Comment: Can you include the code where you get the code value

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a dynamic value, if I understand your question right, for ***code***.  If this is the case, this goes in your embed description, and you can change it to take a variable.  you have right now:

```
.setDescription("Bitcoin Adress: **code**")
```

get your variable, load it with what you want, and call it newCode.  Change your string to use variables with text:

```
.setDescription(`Bitcoin Adress: ***${newCode}***`)
```

keep the "*" if you want them, I preserved, in case that's the formatting you want.  also note the change in quotes from double to `.

Comment: how can i request new codes from the website and then it displays it as a message?

Comment: do you want to change channels, or codes or both?  you should have variables available for both of these.  if you want to post more code, then it can be debugged.